# Android: how to stop fragment change?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to give an alert when leaving a fragment by different ways, and user can choose to stay in the current fragment. Is that possible?

Like there is an activity A and two fragment F1 & F2. Now you are in F2, backbutton lead to F1 and some menu item in A also lead to F1, how I write code in one place to stop both of these two events?
onstop is invoked when fragment stopping, how can I stop this stopping proccess in the onstop method?

Comment: My confusion is an operation like replacing has started, can I stop it and rollback by doing something in the life cycle method?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could override the following methods:

onDestroy
onStop
onPause
onResume
onBackPressed

Comment: There are also some other cases, for example, when you are using NavigationDrawer, or a Button click to trigger fragment change, just put your code to the listener.

Comment: But when I use onStop to show alertDialog, the operation is  not blocked and run behind alert, then cause error. And even it works, what kind of code should I write in dialog to cancel the operation cause onStop such as replace in activity?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the lifecycle methods mentioned by dustedrob, you should also read up on [`onDestroyView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroyView()) and [`onDetach`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDetach()) to see if those suit your needs.

Comment: But when I use onStop to show alertDialog, the operation is  not blocked and run behind alert, then cause error. And even it works, what kind of code should I write in dialog to cancel the operation cause onStop such as replace in activity?

Comment: Edit the original question to tell us all more about exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onBackpressed() of an activity that is attach to all fragment.
Show an alert on Onbackpressed().